# Calling a CFC with multiple arguments using AJAX

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I am using AJAX to call a CFC and I am trying to send over two variables from a query that I ran. My ajax looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"cfcs/get_equipment_details.cfc?method=getDetails",
     dataType: 'json',
     data: { equipment_name: "#equipment_name#", customer_name: "#customer_name#"},
    cache:false,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("Customer Name" + customer_name);

        $.each(response.DATA, function(i, row){
            var id = row[0];
            var customer_name = row[1];
            var equipment_name = row[2];
            var date_last_completed = row[3];
            var maintenance_interval = row[4];
            var last_completed_by = row[5];
            var equipment_notes = row[6];
            var warranty_end_date = row[7];
            var service_Tag = row[8];
            var serial_number = row[9];
            var backup_notes = row[10];
            var TT = row[11];
            $("##customer_name#id#").val(customer_name);
            });
     }
});
```

Here is my CFC:

```
<cffunction name="getDetails" access="remote" output="false" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="equipment_name" type="any" required="true">
    <cfargument name="customer_name" type="any" required="true">

    <!--- Get list of all equipment --->    
    <cfquery name="get_equipment" datasource="#datasource#">
    select *
    from equipment_maintenance
    where equipment_name= <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.equipment_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    AND customer_name= <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.customer_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn get_equipment>
```

But my CFC is throwing an error:

> The parameter customer_name to function getDetails is required but was
>   not passed in.

How can I successfully pass in those two argument and return my query results?

Comment: What does the network tab show as being passed?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo, but you're missing an ending quote for `customer_name`.

Comment: The `cfreturn` tag in your cfc looks troublesome.

Comment: Yes @Chester you were right, I was missing a quote. That helps with a syntax error I was receiving.

Comment: @Chester - I was going to say please post that as an answer, but... someone beat you to it ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing closing `"` for `customer_name` in your data attributes of Ajax function. 
Your Ajax function should look something like this

```
$.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url:"cfcs/get_equipment_details.cfc?method=getDetails",
 data: { equipment_name: "#equipment_name#", customer_name: "#customer_name#"},
        cache:false,
        success: function(msg) {
         $("##customer_name#id#").val(msg); 
    }
 });
```

Now there is some issue with your cfc function. you are returning a variable that dose not exist and its same as your function name. If you do something like this it will work

```
<cffunction name="getDetails" access="remote" output="false" returnformat="JSON">
    <cfargument name="equipment_name" type="any" required="true">
    <cfargument name="customer_name" type="any" required="true">

    <!--- Get list of all equipment --->    
    <cfquery name="get_equipment" datasource="#datasource#">
    select *
    from equipment_maintenance
    where equipment_name= <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.equipment_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    AND customer_name= <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.customer_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn get_equipment.customer_Name>
</cffunction>
```

If you want entire query object to be return as you ajax response then parse JSON on success of  ajax and process it further

Comment: Okay, I see how the <cfreturn> tag makes more sense now. But what information is held in the variable 'msg' in the success function? Is that just whatever data is being sent in the <cfreturn> tag?

Also, my CFC is now throwing this error: can't cast String [All About Care] to a value of type [JSON] - All About Care is a value of the 'customer_name' field that is returned by the query.

Comment: If you are returning entire query Object then CF will convert your query into JSON and then sends it back, So your msg in success will contain a JSON  string that you either need to parse or you can set dataType:"JSON"  to your ajax function in this case it will be parse automatically. If you are returning just one customer_name form query object then you msg in success contain customer_name and you do not need to parse it.

Comment: Okay, so I updated my original post with you suggestions. I am not receiving any errors now in my console, but I am jsut seeing [object Object] in my HTML input field. Is that because I have to still parse that data? I am guessing I need to set this up so that I have JSON to parse because I want to return the whole query with more than one column of data.

Comment: If you are seeing [object Object]  in your HTML input or console, that means JSON  is parsed. Now you just need to process it further as per your need on the page (may be you need to loop through it)

Comment: Thanks. I updated my post with the new code. Seems to be working now.